# VF page to Division/Department breakdown of the Installed Package License Consumption

Tags: community

VF page to Division/Department breakdown of the Installed Package License Consumption

I want to create a visual force page which will show all the installed packages we have .. how many licenses are consumed and which department/division(field on User Detail) consume them. I anyone have any ideas please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following objects to get the details about the managed package and users which has been assigned licenses for the package.

[PackageLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_packagelicense.htm)

[UserPackageLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userpackagelicense.htm)

Now, I am sure, once you have the user ids then you can all the information related to their departments in your apex and then can show them on the visualforce page.

Comment: Thanks Naval. Hoping if someone have done something similar already. So that see and learn.